# How to insert and delete image and text in one view just like MMS apps on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uitextview, mms

I would like to implement something like MMS app on iPhone, where user will have an option to include an image and text.

The way I did is i created a UIUiew and included a UITextView and UIImageView inside it, and when user selects an image it goes in to the UIImageView and the user can type in the UITextView.

But the problem that I am facing is once you insert a UIImage how do you put a cursor after the image so that user can delete(backspace) the image and that space free's up and it becomes available for the user to type in more text.

Comment: We need additional context for your question.  Add a screenshot of your current user interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: You cannot mix text and images in a `UITextView`. If you want to achieve a behavior like this, you should look into using Core Text to render the text yourself (it supports other elements inside the text via certain callbacks through which you tell the text system how much space it is supposed to reserve for the image.

To make the text editable, you would have to implement the text editing protocols `UITextInput` and `UIKeyInput`. Which means you have to basically write your own text editor. It's possible but it's a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks Ole for the suggestions, do you know of any any open source project looking at which I can get some idea